# Drawing image to a canvas with 8 Parameters not Working

Tags: javascript, html, drawimage

I understand that this isn't a question about a general code problem but I really just need help fixing my code. Right now, I'm working on my first HTML5 program on my own, and it's a really simple top down shooter. Right now, I've got the code written so that a ship appears on the screen that you can move side to side. However, now I'm trying to create a new object to draw called bullet. I kind of copied the code from the ship, but I can't get it to work. So far, here is the code. It's fairly small, so you can understand the ship. Here's the ship object:

```
function ship() {
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 75;
    this.drawX = gameWidth/2 - this.width/2;
    this.drawY = gameHeight - this.height - 5;
}
```

Do draw that, I use this function:

```
ship.prototype.draw = function() {
    clearCtx(ctxPlayer);
    var srcX;
    var srcY;
    if(isRightKey) {
        srcX = 0;
        srcY = 75;
    } else if (isLeftKey) {
        srcX = 0;
        srcY = 153;
    } else {
        srcX= 0;
        srcY = 0;
    }

    ctxPlayer.drawImage(sprites,srcX,srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY, this.width, this.height);
}
```

That stuff towards the top only changes the source of the image because the image is different if it's moving one way or another. Anyway, here's the bullet object:

```
function BulletGreen() {
    var drawX = 0;
    var drawY = 0;
    var height = 33;
    var width = 9;
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty similar. Now, here's the code I use to draw it:

```
BulletGreen.prototype.draw = function drawBulletsGreen() {
    ctxPlayer.drawImage(sprites,350,0,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY, this.width, this.height);
}
```

However, this just doesn't seem to work when I use the command in the console. It returns no errors but doesn't seem to change the canvas at all. However, doing something like

```
ctxBullet.drawImage(sprites,0,0)
```

Will draw out the sprite sheet onto the canvas. I apologize if this sort of question isn't welcome here, but I'm just out of ideas! It's really confusing me.

Edit: I uploaded everything  here .

Comment: Is your example online?  Or can you upload the full code somewhere or create a jsFiddle?

Comment: I don't think I can do a fiddle because it uses images, but I'll try to upload the code.

Comment: Ok, I added the full program.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got you correct : 
ctxPlayer is your canvas object and sprites is new image src ( for example abc.png ) then instead of using 8 parameters for drawimage can you use only 5 of them? In your case I think those will be ,

```
ctxPlayer.drawImage(sprites,this.drawX,this.drawY, this.width, this.height);
```

where,

```
this.drawX is the x coordinate where to place the image on the canvas
this.drawY is the x coordinate where to place the image on the canvas
this.width is width of the image
this.height is height of the image
```

Similar parameters worked for me .. I think they will work for you too :)

This is reference url that I found : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Also in clearCtx(ctxPlayer); Are you clearing the entire canvas or where the previous image was drawn? If you are trying to clear the entire canvas you will have to redraw again completely

Comment: Well, I'm drawing off of a sprite sheet so I need 8 parameters. Why isn't 8 working though?